# Is it possible to run standard algorithms on vector<MyType> in an elegant way?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I know if I have a `vector<int>` I can run algorithms on it like so:

```
int max = *max_element(myints.begin(), myints.end());
```

But what if I have a `vector<MyStruct>` where one of the fields within the struct is an int.  Is there a nice elegant way to run an algorithm on just the ints in all of my structs?

Comment: It depends one your definition of "elegant" and if you have C++11 support.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "elegant", and can you use boost.phoenix and/or C++11 lamdbas?

Comment: There are no `int`-based algorithms in C++ (STL), algorithms are generic.

Comment: loki, when I say int based, I mean a generic algorithm applied to one of the ints in my struct.

Comment: Certain algorithms rely on comparison operators, so you can overload them and use the "elegant" calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Provide a comparator to max_element:

```
MyStruct max = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](const MyStruct & lhs, const MyStruct & rhs) { return lhs.theInt < rhs.theInt; });
```

If your compiler does not yet support lambdas, you will have to write a separate function or function object class.

Alternatively, if you overload `operator<` for your class to do this same comparison, then you can simply do this:

```
MyStruct max = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what your definition of "elegant" is, but yes, this can be done.  In fact, in many different ways.

In Standard C++, you can use a Functor:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Gizmo
{
public:
    int n_;
};

class BiggestGizmo : public std::binary_function<bool, Gizmo, Gizmo>
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Gizmo& lhs, const Gizmo& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.n_ > rhs.n_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef vector<Gizmo> Gizmos;
    Gizmos gizmos;
    Gizmos::const_iterator it = max_element(gizmos.begin(), gizmos.end(), BiggestGizmo());
}
```

In C++0X, you could use a Lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Gizmo
{
public:
    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    typedef vector<Gizmo> Gizmos;
    Gizmos gizmos;
    Gizmos::const_iterator it = max_element(gizmos.begin(), gizmos.end(), [](const Gizmo& lhs, const Gizmo& rhs) -> bool
    {
        return lhs.n_ > rhs.n_;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option in the mix: you could write an iterator class of your own whose reference and value types are `int&` and `int`, but which acts on top of an iterator with reference type `MyStruct&`, providing access to that field.

It's a bit more work than just supplying an extra comparator to `max_element`, but if you do it once, then you've done it for *all* algorithms, not just the ones that act via a comparator. If you can use it, `boost::transform_iterator` will handle the boilerplate for you.

`boost::transform_iterator` doesn't let you get the underlying iterator back from an instance, but in the case of `vector` that doesn't matter too much since it's random-access, so it's efficient to compute the distance and apply it to the `begin()` iterator.

Comment: +1 for interesting.  But out of curiosity, what kind of algorithms did you have in mind?  Any specifically?

Comment: @Benjamin: Anything that doesn't use a comparator, really. Suppose you wanted to run `std::accumulate` to add up the integers in all the structs in the vector. If you've already written the comparator as in your answer, then it's no use, you still have to write an addition function (or an `operator+` for `mystruct`, if applicable). If you already have an iterator adaptor, you can use the same one for `accumulate` and `max_element`.

Comment: A really interesting alternative to the comparator approach, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

For structs you can define a comparison function or object. You can also define the `<` operator for your struct. Here's a [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/).

Comment: I could do this if I only wanted to do one type of algorithm on the struct.  However, in my case the struct has 20 fields which are ints/floats/doubles and I want to produce statistics based on those fields.  Obviously I could write something to do this by looping but I wanted to see if there was a more STL way of doing it...

Comment: @Benj: Than write the same thing as free function or functor. All the algorithms take the appropriate operator as an optional last argument.

Comment: @Benj: The `max_element` finds the maximum in whatever way you define it to be (i.e. using whatever comparator your provide). If you need to find the max of several different fields separately, you will need to define several different comparators. You have to tell the function in some way what you mean by max for it to work, there is no way around it. This is basically true for any other comparison based function in the STL.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in one of the comments you have many class members and want to address each individually in algorithms. You end up with various possibilities

- lambdas everywhere (either Phoenix or C++11)
- functors for every case
- member functions for every case

I'd prefer the last two solutions only if I would need to repeat the
lambdas in different places (or if I had to use Phoenix, but this is
just a personal thing).

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool less_than_by_a(const Foo&) const;
  bool less_than_by_b(const Foo&) const;
};

std::max_element(begin, end, std::mem_fun_ref(&Foo::less_than_by_a));
std::max_element(begin, end, std::mem_fun_ref(&Foo::less_than_by_b));
```